# Adding PDF template page to new inserted page. using itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have created one pdf file that i want to use as template page (contain header and border), so when i add new page to existing pdf it automatically set header and border to newly added page.

I am using `ITextSharp` PDF library.

I have try using **PdfImportedPage** as below but it's not working:

```
PdfReader templateFile;
templateFile = new PdfReader("D:\\templatefile.pdf");

PdfImportedPage template_page;
var fileStream1 = new FileStream("D:\\temp.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

var stamper1 = new PdfStamper(templateFile, fileStream1);
template_page = stamper1.GetImportedPage(templateFile, 1);

// now i want to add this template_page to existing pdf at specific position    

//this is the file(existingpdf.pdf) in which i want to add template_page create above using stamper
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("D:\\existingpdf.pdf");

var reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
var numberofPages = reader.NumberOfPages;
var fileStream = new FileStream("D:\\result.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

//stamper of result pdf
var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fileStream);

stamper.InsertPage(numberofPages + 1, templateFile.GetPageSize(1));

//below code i have tried to add template but its not working in result pdf
stamper.GetUnderContent(2).AddTemplate(template_page, 0, 0);

stamper.Close();
```

Comment: *"so when i add new page to existing pdf it automatically set header and border to newly added page."* - do I understand you correctly, you only want to add the template as background to new pages? In that case how do you plan to create those new pages?

Comment: Yes . after setting template i want add table in that page. (i know how to add table but unable to set template)

Comment: In that case how do you plan to create those new pages?

Comment: I found that stamper may be useful. using importpage and addTemplate method. by the way thanks for your time..i just come to solution using by creating new document. Thanks.

Comment: *"i just come to solution using by creating new document"* - In that case you would add the template as `UnderContent` in a page event listener. As you say you came to a solution, I assume you know that.